# Email address has already been taken

Tags: android, parse-platform, parseexception

I have randomly this error when I try to `saveInBackground` a `ParseObject` on Android app :

> com.parse.ParseException: the email address  has already been taken

I never set an email address to my user, i do only a Facebook login with `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground`

Can you tell me how to stop this error ?

Comment: log into parse and check users table.

Comment: remember also that parse will retire next year.

Comment: yea i know unfortunately but i need to correct this bug quickly ;)
My users emails are empty, i have this exception only on android and randomly...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but just in case somebody stumbles on this (as i did) you might wanna check what if the email address you get from Facebook is not null or empty. If it is and you use .setEmail("") you will get that error.